# How to delete record from database by using input form in django

Tags: python, django, sqlite

So i have this small web program in which a user can enter his/her email and receives some updates. Nevertheless this email is saved in the database (sqlite3) and i have a form in which a user can unsubscribe, my problem is i'm trying to find a way to take the input from the unsubscribe form & if it matches any record in the database it deletes it. Does anyone have any suggestions?

> This is the view i'm trying to create but doesn't work

```
def unsubscribe_view(request):

    form = EmailForm()

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = EmailForm(request.POST)
        value = form.cleaned_data['email']
        if form.is_valid():
            Email.objects.filter(email = value).delete()

    context = {
        'form' : form,
    }

    return render(request, 'Version/unsubscribe.html', context)
```

> This is the html page

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

    <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<div style="text-align : center;">
<h1> UnSubscribe Page </h1>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
<form method="post" action="/">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form}}
    <button type="submit" class="waves-effect waves-light btn-small">Unsubscribe</button>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

> This is the model if its any helpful

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Email(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

> This is the form

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Email

class EmailForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Email
        fields = ['email']
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that the record be invalidated instead of a delete. But in case you are sure about deletion, then the below snippet can do the job

```
emailInstance = Email.objects.get(email='<email value>')
emailInstance.delete()
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response, i tried the code but anytime i input the email in the unsubscribe field it saves it to the database instead of deleting

Comment: Did you add the snippet to your form class for request.method = DELETE ?  Check :https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/